# Webpack cannot find ./homedir while deploying

Tags: spring, gradle, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to deploy app to Heroku, but it fails with `[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module './homedir'.`
When I run `./gradlew build` in my console, everything works perfectly, but the moment I'm trying to push into heroku remote it fails with this error.
This is full error stack trace:
https://pastebin.com/wRLBgBXz

Answer (score 0):

The thing was, I forgot to remove cached files from git, after adding `node_modules` to `.gitignore`

Also I moved all devDependencies into dependencies because of Heroku installation